# can't download stock data using getSymbols() from quantmod, get SSL error with curl

Tags: r, macos, curl

I am trying to use quantmod's getSymbols. `getSymbols("AAPL", src = "yahoo", from = start, to = end)`
I am getting this error:

"Error in curl::curl_download(cu, tmp, handle = h) : 
  SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate"

I have uninstalled quantmod and curl, ignored SSL errors `(httr::set_config(config(ssl_verifypeer = FALSE))`) and reinstalled quantmod and curl.  I also ran this code: `brew install libcurl4-openssl-dev`.

I still get the error.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my internet connection was the problem. I switched to my mobile data and the code worked fine.